# installing gdal from osgeo to work with GeoTIFF

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, installation, osgeo

I just installed Anaconda Navigator (and nothing else) in Windows and want to be able to work with GeoTIFF files in
Spider (Python 3.7).
It is my understanding that Navigator can search for packages on Anaconda Cloud or in a local Anaconda Repository, but I do not know how to install what I need and have the following response:

File "C:/Users/igor/.anaconda/test.py", line 2, in 
    from osgeo import gdal

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'osgeo'

It seems that I need to get osgeo first, but I do not have such experience either.  Would you please help knowing that I did not use Conda at all.

Comment: I would recommend creating a "virtual environment" before playing around with this. If you don't know Conda at all, you should do some reading: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html A virtual environment is a self-contained set of packages that is very useful, especially when working on many projects that require different versions of various packages and/or Python.

Answer (score 4):

Open Anaconda Prompt and write the following command: `conda install gdal`. This will install `osgeo` where both `gdal` (to manipulate raster data) and `ogr` (to manipulate vector data) are stored.

[image]

Comment: You should definitely install that from conda-forge, so add `-c conda-forge`.